# Android not able to stop service

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app i am using a Service that periodically checks if there is a new personal message for the logged in user.
The service is started if the user enables the notification feature. Now if the user disables the notification feature i would like to stop the service.

I try to stop the service with the following lines of code.

```
Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);
                stopService(service);
```

The problem is that the service doesn't stop. It goes on working.

Here you can see my message service.

```
public class MessageService extends Service {

private int intervall;


public MessageService(){
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);

    Bundle intentData = intent.getExtras();
    if(intentData != null) {
        this.intervall = intentData.getInt("intervall");
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            // async task for calling api otherwise we get an exeception here
            new ServiceMessagesTask().execute(MessageService.this);
        }
    };

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(intervall); // repeat after given intervall
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

I have an activity where the user can edit his preferences. There it is also possible to activate the notification feature.

The notification service is started or stoped in the savePreferences() method:

```
public void savePreferences(View button) {
    EditText login      = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbLogin);
    EditText password   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbPassword);
    CheckBox enableNotification = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbNotifications);
    Spinner spinner     = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.notificationInterval);

    if(!login.getText().equals("") && !password.getText().equals("")){
        Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        preferences.put("document_type", CouchbaseHelper.CB_VIEW_USER_PREFERENCES);
        preferences.put("login", login.getText().toString());
        preferences.put("password", password.getText().toString());

        if(enableNotification.isChecked()){
            preferences.put("enableNotification", true);
        } else {
            preferences.put("enableNotification", false);
        }

        preferences.put("notificationInterval", this.notificationInterval);

        CouchbaseHelper couchbaseHelper = new CouchbaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        String documentId = couchbaseHelper.createDocUserPreferences(preferences);
        couchbaseHelper.closeDb();

        // start notification service if enabled
        if(enableNotification.isChecked()){
            Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);
            service.putExtra("intervall", Integer.valueOf(this.notificationInterval)*60*1000);
            startService(service);
        } else {
            // TODO: this is not working!!! service doesnt stop
            // try to stop running service
            if(isMyServiceRunning()){
                Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);
                stopService(service);
            }
        }
    }

    finish();
    Intent main = new Intent(Preferences.this, Main.class);
    startActivity(main);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you really don't get what a service is, service is just a component that do not require UI and is not linked to an activity life cycle, hence it runs in background, BUT background doesn't necessarily means in a separate thread, actually the service runs in the main thread, now that's one thing, killing a service doesn't mean you are killing all the working threads you create within, and in your code you are creating a Thread that is looping forever, that thread although created in the service is not linked in any way to the service life cycle.

So, if you want to stop the thread, get a reference to the thread you are creating in the startCommand method and in the onDestroy method just stop it, instead of having a while(true) validation, go for a flag and just change it to false in the onDestroy so it will stop the thread you created when started the service.

Regards!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, don't forget to mark it as correct to help other people finding the right answer to the same question